# Custom Post Type Capabilities Singular/Plural

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

Just for clearance, if i add a custom post type with:

```
register_post_type( 'event',
    array(
        'labels' => array(…),
        'capability_type' => ['event','events'],
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    )
);
```

what are the resulting capabilitites? (Singular/Plural)

```
'read_event'
'read_events'
```

I can not find a minimum variant that works. In all my projects i just double the capabilities, once singular, once plural... but i think that's shitty. Can anyone clear out when to user singular, and when to use plural?

Comment: `'capability_type' => ['event','events'],` is a perfectly acceptable way to define capabilities for your post type. What's shitty about it?

Comment: not the definition is the problem, the question is: whats the resulting capabilitites? are all of them singular "read_event, delete_event, delete_others_event" or are they all plural "delete_events, read_events, delete_others_events"? It seems they are mixed, and i newer know which ones are the right ones. @JacobPeattie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, the answer lies in the documentation. In [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for `register_post_type()` you'll see:

> - **'capability_type'**
>     *(string)* The string to use to build the read, edit, and delete capabilities. May be passed as an array to allow for alternative
>     plurals when using this argument as a base to construct the
>     capabilities, e.g. array('story', 'stories'). Default 'post'.
> - **'capabilities'**
>     *(array)* Array of capabilities for this post type. $capability_type is used as a base to construct capabilities by default. See
>     [get_post_type_capabilities()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_capabilities/).

So `capability_type` uses the singular and plural strings provided to fill the `capabilities` argument, and if we follow [that link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_capabilities/) to the documentation for `get_post_type_capabilities()` we can see the full list of capabilities (emphasis mine):

> By default, seven keys are accepted as part of the capabilities array:
>
> - **edit_post**, **read_post**, and **delete_post** are meta capabilities, which are
>     then generally mapped to corresponding primitive capabilities
>     depending on the context, which would be the post being
>     edited/read/deleted and the user or role being checked. Thus these
>     capabilities would generally not be granted directly to users or
>     roles.
> - **edit_posts** – Controls whether objects of this post type can be edited.
> - **edit_others_posts** – Controls whether objects of this type owned by
>     other users can be edited. If the post type does not support an
>     author, then this will behave like edit_posts.
> - **publish_posts** – Controls publishing objects of this post type.
> - **read_private_posts** – Controls whether private objects can be read.
>
> These four primitive capabilities are checked in core in various
>   locations. There are also seven other primitive capabilities which are
>   not referenced directly in core, except in [map_meta_cap()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/), which takes
>   the three aforementioned meta capabilities and translates them into
>   one or more primitive capabilities that must then be checked against
>   the user or role, depending on the context.
>
> - **read** – Controls whether objects of this post type can be read.
> - **delete_posts** – Controls whether objects of this post type can be
>     deleted.
> - **delete_private_posts** – Controls whether private objects can
>     be deleted.
> - **delete_published_posts** – Controls whether published
>     objects can be deleted.
> - **delete_others_posts** – Controls whether objects
>     owned by other users can be can be deleted. If the post type does not
>     support an author, then this will behave like delete_posts.
> - **edit_private_posts** – Controls whether private objects can be edited.
> - **edit_published_posts** – Controls whether published objects can be
>     edited.

So by passing `['event','events']` all those capabilities with `post` will created but with `event` (eg. `edit_event`), and all the capabilities with `posts` will be created but with `events` (eg. `edit_events`). However, note that just passing `'event'` to `capability_type` will have the exact same result. This is because if only a single value is passed WordPress will automatically add `s` for the plural. The only reason you'd need to pass the singular and plural versions separately is if the plural version is not just the same plus "s", such as story vs stories (if you only passed `'story'` then the plural capabilities would be like `edit_storys`).

Comment: I've read the documentation, but can say, if i add_cap('edit_event') to my administrator role, the event-post-type is missing in admin menu. if i add_cap('edit_events') it shows up. Reading the Documentation i thought edit_event should map to edit_events?

Comment: As described in the docs, the singular versions "are meta capabilities, which are then generally mapped to corresponding primitive capabilities **depending on the context**, which would be the post being edited/read/deleted and the user or role being checked. Thus these capabilities would generally **not be granted directly to users or roles.**"

Comment: So you shouldn't be using `add_cap('edit_event')`. It doesn't make sense for a user to be able to "edit event". What event? A user can `edit_events` or `edit_others_events`. `edit_event` is mapped to either of those dynamically based on whether the user is the author of the event in question.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out.